Populate Cell B with specific details from Cell A
I have a spreadsheet with over 10,000 rows and I need to obtain certain details only from one cell and populate 2 others. I started using =MID but as the details I need are in different parts of each cell it would take a very long time. Is there anyway I can do this quickly?
Example:



Asset Description
ELR
Mileage




End Support: ALK 22.0429 - Cwmbach Station
Empty Cell
Empty Cell


Underline Bridge: Up Side - CAM 5.0583 - Llandaff to Radyr
Empty Cell
Empty Cell



What I need to do:



Asset Description
ELR
Mileage




End Support: ALK 22.0429 - Cwmbach Station
ALK
22.0429


Underline Bridge: Up Side - CAM 5.0583 - Llandaff to Radyr
CAM
5.0583



I need the 3 letter ELR, in these case ALK and CAM in one cell and mileage 22.0429 and 5.0583 in each of their representative cells. As you can see using MID would require many changes as the asset description is only duplicated 50 or 60 times each.

With such issues there are always a require that what is the enabled structure of the input string. To get a proper solution it would be necessary to define. (E.g. multiple spaces, dash position/exist, numbers occurencies etc.) If such parameters are not exactly defined the workarounds will lead to unwanted results.

Assuming there is no Excel Constraints as per the tags posted, therefore the following should work accordingly:


• Formula used in cell B2
=LET(a, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A2," -",-1)," ",-2)," "), IFERROR(--a,a))



Using TEXTBEFORE() function : Extract the value before the  - from last instance.
Using TEXTAFTER() function : Applying on the above, to return from the last two instances where space is a delimiter.
Using TEXTSPLIT() function : Applying on the above, to return the desired output.
Finally, wrapping the whole into one and using within LET() where the total formula is defined as variable a, since we need the mileage in numbers, therefore, using an IFERROR() function and double unary to check if the return a is a number or not, if its a number, give me the number else if its not return as is.


Another alternative based on the update posted by OP:


=DROP(REDUCE("",A2:A4,LAMBDA(a,b,
 LET(c,TEXTSPLIT(b,," "),
     d,INDEX(c,XMATCH(--TOCOL(--c,3),--c)+{-1,0}),
     VSTACK(a,IFERROR(--d,d))))),1)


Data can be copied:



Asset Description
ELR
Mileage




End Support: ALK 22.0429 - Cwmbach Station
ALK
22.0429


Underline Bridge: Up Side - CAM 5.0583 - Llandaff to Radyr
CAM
5.0583


Abutment: CAR 22.0875 - Down Side - Pontlottyn to Tir-phil
CAR
22.0875


Access Route: CAR 13.0726 - Up Side - Ystrad Mynach South Jcn
CAR
13.0726


Accessible Batteries (UPS): CAR 8.0109 - DN - Lisvane & Thornhill to Caerphilly
CAR
8.0109


Adjustment Switch: CAM 0.1331 - Cardiff Bay Chord - Cardiff Bay to Cardiff Queen Street
CAM
0.1331


Adjustment Switch: CAM 1.0330 - Down Line - Cardiff Queen Street Station
CAM
1.033





That worked great thank you. Would you mind explaining what it's actually doing becuase it makes no sense, I just copy and pasted and it worked.

@NotVeryBright Sure.

There are some it hasn't worked for and I'm guessing it's becuase it has more than 1 dash (-)  example - Abutment: CAR 22.0875 - Down Side - Pontlottyn to Tir-phil  I'm trying to work out what I need to do as it will help me understand how the forumla works

@NotVeryBright post few more examples, to understand the pattern. This seems inconsistent with the above two posted in your original OP

@NotVeryBright you should be posting the sample in the post, not in comments

=LET(_wrds, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(A2, ":"), " ", , TRUE),
     ELR, REDUCE(NA(), 
                 _wrds,
                 LAMBDA(_a, 
                        _w, 
                        IFERROR(_a, 
                                IF(AND(EXACT(_w, UPPER(_w)), LEN(_w)=3), 
                                   _w,
                                   NA()
                                )
                        )
                 )
     ),
     milage, INDEX(_wrds, MATCH(ELR, _wrds, 0)+1),
     HSTACK(ELR, IFERROR(--milage, milage))
)

This will take all of the text after the first ":" and split it into individual words (i.e. separated by spaces) as _wrds
Next, it will use REDUCE to find the first word that is both ALL CAPS and 3 Letters long, and then use INDEX and MATCH to find the word immediately following that.
Finally, it will output both of those, while trying to convert the milage from text into a number.
(You can change TEXTAFTER(A2, ":") to just A2 if you want to ignore the 'text after ":"' test and just grab the very first 3-letter all-caps word in the whole thing as ELR)
Note that this formula will fail if ELR is ever not ALL CAPS or not 3 letters long

Would I paste this into excel?

Yup; paste it into the formula bar for cell B2, and it will fill out both B2 and C2 for you

If REGEXEXTRACT is available in your Excel version:
with regular expression,

group for ELR [A-Z]{3})
group for Mileage (\d+\.?\d*)

formula for fill-down:
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "([A-Z]{3})\s+(\d+\.?\d*)\s+", 2)

spill formula (spilled results for 10k rows in about 3 seconds on my Mac):
=REDUCE(
    {"ELR", "Mileage"},
    A2:A3,
    LAMBDA(acc, cur,
        VSTACK(acc, REGEXEXTRACT(cur, "([A-Z]{3})\s+(\d+\.?\d*)\s+", 2))
    )
)



A Regex Extract

Using Regex, extract a space followed by 3 uppercase letters followed by a space and a digit.
To get the ELR, remove the spaces and the trailing digit from the extracted string.
To get the Milage, concatenate the trailing digit with the right part of the string split by the extracted string and finally remove the characters to the right of the first space inclusive (after the digits).

Single Line
=LET(data,A2,
    m,REGEXEXTRACT(data," [A-Z]{3} \d"),
    ls,IFERROR(MID(m,2,LEN(m)-3),""),
    rs,IFERROR(--TEXTBEFORE(RIGHT(m,1)&TEXTAFTER(data,m)," "),""),
    HSTACK(ls,rs))

Whole Column
=LET(data,A2:A11,
    re,BYROW(data, LAMBDA(r,REGEXEXTRACT(r," [A-Z]{3} \d"))),
    MAKEARRAY(ROWS(re),2,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(
       e,INDEX(re,r),
       IFERROR(IF(c=1,MID(e,2,LEN(e)-3),
           --TEXTBEFORE(RIGHT(e,1)&TEXTAFTER(INDEX(data,r),e)," ")),"")))))

